# Overflow scroll + visible

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container that has overflow:scroll while a child of it needs to be shown anyways like overflow: visible.

How to solve that?

Comment: You should post your code, for more accurate answers. Otherwise people will just 'assume' somethings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats an easy one:

give your parent

```
position: relative;
```

your child

```
position: fixed;
```

use margin to change the position

**Dont** use top, bottom etc.